# How Can i save .msg file as a draft Server to client machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a .msg file and i want to save as a draft serve to Client Machine on Link button click
Here is my Button code

<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" Text="Email Draft" CommandName="SendDraft" HeaderText="" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridview-header" >

</asp:ButtonField>

An here is my button behind code which is creat .msg file and download .msg file Client to server machine
if (e.CommandName == "SendDraft")
{

```
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);


        string JROPID = gvReleaseOrderEmail.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text.Trim();
        string ReleaseOrderNo = gvReleaseOrderEmail.Rows[index].Cells[2].Text.Trim();

        DataTable Report = Utilities.GetDataTable2("exec SP_JobEstReleaseOrderPress '" + Session["Compcode"].ToString().Trim() + "','" + JROPID.Trim() + "'");
        ReportDocument crystalReport;
        crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
        crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath(@"~\Modules\JobOrder\Reports\JobEstReleaseOrderPress.rpt"));
        crystalReport.SetDataSource(Report);
        DataRow dr = Report.Rows[0];

        ExportOptions exportOptions = new ExportOptions();
        DiskFileDestinationOptions diskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
        string pdfFilePath = Server.MapPath(@"~/Modules/JobOrder/Reports/" + ReleaseOrderNo.Trim() + ".pdf");
        diskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = pdfFilePath;
        exportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
        exportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
        exportOptions.ExportDestinationOptions = diskFileDestinationOptions;
        crystalReport.Export(exportOptions);


        crystalReport.Close();
        crystalReport.Dispose();

        string toEmail = gvReleaseOrderEmail.Rows[index].Cells[9].Text.Trim(); // Assuming Email field is at index 8
        string subject = dr["EmailSubject"].ToString();
        string Body = dr["Body"].ToString();
        string ccEmail = dr["cc"].ToString();
        string attachmentPath = pdfFilePath; // Path to your attachment file

        try
        {



            var senders = new Sender("Nadeem", dr["MailFrom"].ToString());
            var msg = new Email(senders, subject);

            msg.Recipients.AddTo(toEmail);
            msg.Recipients.AddCc(ccEmail);
            msg.Subject = subject;
            msg.BodyHtml = Body;
            msg.Attachments.Add(attachmentPath);


            string msgFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/Modules/JobOrder/Reports//" + ReleaseOrderNo.ToString().Trim() + ".msg");

            if (File.Exists(msgFilePath))
            {
                File.Delete(msgFilePath);
            }


            msg.Save(msgFilePath);

            msg.Dispose();


            if (File.Exists(attachmentPath))
            {
                File.Delete(attachmentPath);
            }

            string script = "window.open('" + ResolveUrl("~/Modules/JobOrder/Reports/" + ReleaseOrderNo.Trim() + ".msg") + "', '_blank');";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "DownloadScript", script, true);




        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: And... What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is when user open download .msg file the file is not editable that's why i want to save .msg file as a draft
i try outlook library to direct save on outlook draft it's work on local when i publish the code then I'm facing error for security restriction on server to client machine outlook

Comment: I don't think you can download a message to someone's outlook... Exactly for security reasons. You can only serve a download and the user has to add/open it in outlook.

Comment: You cannot. You can only download a msg file. The user then has to decide what to do with it.

Comment: Thanks For guiding me  @VDWWD